# BLAKE2s finding a hash collision

Tags: hash, blake2

I want to find a hash collision for Blake2 with 32 bit digest length such that i have 2 messages that produce an identical hash digest. How would you do that? is there another option than just bruteforce?

I tried brute forcing but that doesn't seem to work out nicely since the hash space is already quite large with 32 bits.
Also i didn't find any vulnerabilities online regarding the BLAKE2s hash algorithm.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149783/discussion-on-question-by-guestlian-blake2s-finding-a-hash-collision); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I've closed the question and moved the comments to chat. If you have any issues continuing the discussion there please let me know by commenting below or flagging the question if that doesn't work.